# Using multimap and struct in C++

Tags: c++, vector, insert, multimap

```
typedef struct
{
string idArtigo;
string tituloArtigo;
string veiculoPublicacao;
vector<string> autores;
}Publicacao;
```

I have a vector like :

```
vector<Publicacao> pub(1000);
```

and:

```
multimap<int,Publicacao> multimapa;   
multimap<int,Publicacao>::iterator it;
```

Im using insert to add:

```
multimapa.insert ( pair<int,Publicacao>(i,p[i]));
multimapa.insert ( pair<int,Publicacao>(i,p[j]));
```

The problem is, when im print, i cant print the vector autores of the struct, just the other variables, like:

```
    for (it=multimapa.begin(); it!=multimapa.end(); ++it)
    {
    arquivoResultado<<"Codigo Unico: "<< (*it).first<<endl;  //works
    arquivoResultado<<"Titulo: "<<(*it).second.tituloArtigo<<endl; //works
    arquivoResultado<<"Autores: "<<endl; // works
    for(i=0; (*it).second.autores.size(); i++) // NOT WORKS
    {
        arquivoResultado<<(*it).second.autores[i]<<" "; //FAIL EXECUTION

    } 
    arquivoResultado <<"\nVeiculo: "<<(*it).second.veiculoPublicacao<<endl;                             
}
```

Just the vector of the struct have a problem in execution time, and i have no idea why.

Comment: Are not you missing some syntax? Like `i < (*it).second.autores.size();`

Comment: not even  arquivoResultado<<(*it).second.autores[0]; works, like something is wrong and cant acess this item, or im missing the correct syntaxe really.

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Wait, it worked now: or(int i=0; i <(*it).second.autores.size(); ++i)
        {
            arquivoResultado<<(*it).second.autores[i];

        }  idk how, ty man.

Comment: Note that `(*it).second` is equivalent to `it->second` and operator `->` created specially for this case

Comment: And do not use `typedef struct` in C++

Comment: Why do you write `(*it).` instead of just `it->`?

Comment: Why would you write `it->` instead of just `p.`? Following `for (auto& p : multimap)` of course!

Comment: Ty for the tips guys.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of your `for loop` is not complete. It should look something similar to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (*it).second.autores.size(); i++) // missing "i < " and the declaration of i
{
    arquivoResultado << (*it).second.autores[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, you loop while the size of the vector was larger than zero, which will be true or false forever. As written in your comment, once you changed it to loop while the index was smaller than the size it began working correctly.